# How to run roscore as a daemon

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since virtually everything in ROS seems to require roscore to be running, and there should only be one instance of it per machine, does it make sense to run it as a daemon/service process on Ubuntu and make it start at boot time? If so, why is this not the default configuration? Googling shows a few people have non-standard solutions for accomplishing this, but nothing in the [roscore wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roscore) suggests this is even desirable.

I feel this may be confusing a lot of newcomers, like myself, since most of the tutorials don't mention you need to start `roscore` before you run any commands/nodes, and the errors you get for failing to do so are usually unhelpful and nothing along the lines of "roscore isn't running!"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208411/how-to-run-roscore-as-a-daemon/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2015-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might want to look into creating a launch file see **roslaunch**, it will start and stop roscore for you.  Plus you can have as many nodes as you want and it only takes up one terminal.

http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch

If you are want to run  a node(s) every time you boot up your computer have a look at the robot_upstart package.
http://wiki.ros.org/robot_upstart

---

Originally posted by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) with karma: 258 on 2015-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3